# Toolchain for any ARM processor

Tags: arm

Can a  toolchain for any ARM processor be used to compile any operating system? What is the dependency of toolchain on OS?

My problem may sound trivial...I have no idea about toolchains for ARM.

Answer (score 4):

> Can a toolchain for any Arm processor be used to compile any
>   Operating system?

It depends on the target OS. If it has support for the ARM architecture (such as Linux) then only configuration and patches are missing, but generally yes.

> What is the dependency of toolchain on
>   OS?

I'm only experienced in [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), so I'd say [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), [glibc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)+[kernel headers](http://www.kernel.org/) and then [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). If you want threads, you'd need pthreads too.

See this article on how to bootstrap [Linux on ARM](http://www.ailis.de/~k/archives/19-ARM-cross-compiling-howto.html). While it's rather old, the same process applies, with appropriate patches.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [BuildRoot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/) for building a toolchain to target Arm and other processors.

Answer (score 0):

In general, no.  The toolchain has compiler libraries that depend on the system libC libraries, and these come from the operating system (unless you're compiling for small "bare metal" systems without an operating system, in which case they come from somewhere else).

Thus, programs compiled with a given toolchain will only work on systems with a compatible libC.  For instance, if you have a toolchain for ARM GlibC-based systems, it will work to compile programs for standard ARM Linux systems that use GlibC, but won't work on ARM uClinux systems that use uClibc, or on ARM bare-metal systems using Newlib.

There are some other minor dependencies as well (which I'm less familiar with), but that's the biggest one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many cross platform compiler are available even many version of gcc also provides... to compile kernel for arm you need to get cross compiler and change the top level Makefile of kernel folder ex: ARCH = arm and CROSS_COMPILE = arm-linux-, the CROSS_COMPILE argument depends on where u kept the gcc-cross-platform tool...

Here ARCH stands for Architecture